# Can't find a way to properly pass data with intent b.w two activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Whenever I move from 1st activity to 2nd acitivity and then come back to 1st activity the value given in 1st activity goes null , even when I'm passing the value back and forth through intent .

**Activity - 1**

```
String date = getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");



            textView1.setText(date);
            textView2.setText(name);



        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Main.this,date.class);
                intent.putExtra("name1", name);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Activity - 2**

```
calendarView=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        String name1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                String date = dayOfMonth+"-"+month+"-"+year;
                Intent intent = new Intent(date.this , Main.class);
                intent.putExtra("date", date);
                intent.putExtra("name", name1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You are not getting the data back because you are starting a new activity rather than  getting back to your previous activity.Use startactivity for result then from the other activity just set the result

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as this tag is for problems/questions related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the data back because you are starting a new activity rather than  getting back to your previous activity
From your first activity ,start activity for result

```
int LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY = 1
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY);
```

from your second activity return the result

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

finaly on your first activity,receive the results from the second activity on onActivityResult

```
Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
} //onActivityResult
```